# Extract string from PDF that contains a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf4

I have a PDF document with a few hyperlinks in it, and I need to extract the text/string from the pdf that contains a url. I have used the PyPDF2 and PyPDF4.

I am able to extract the urls but unable to extract the string that contains the url.

For example, I have text that says [Check this link out](https://stackoverflow.com), with a link attached to it in PDF. I am able to extract the link https://stackoverflow.com  bu I also need **Check this link out**.

```
import PyPDF4
import requests

# Open the PDF file
pdf_file = open('abc.pdf', 'rb')

# Create a PDF reader object
pdf_reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

# Loop through each page of the PDF
for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
    # Get the page object
    page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]

    # Extract the annotations from the page
    annotations = page.get('/Annots')

    # If there are no annotations, skip to the next page
    if not annotations:
        continue

    # Loop through each annotation
    for annotation in annotations:
        # Get the annotation dictionary
        annotation_dict = annotation.getObject()

        # If the annotation is a link, extract the URL and its associated string
        if annotation_dict.get('/Subtype') == '/Link':
            url_dict = annotation_dict.get('/A')

            if url_dict is not None:
                url = url_dict.get('/URI')
                url_string = annotation_dict.get('/Contents')

                if url is not None:
                    # Check if the URL is working or broken
                    try:
                        response = requests.get(url)

                        if response.status_code == 200:
                            print(f"Page {page_num + 1}: URL - {url}\nString - {url_string}\nWorking fine!")
                        else:
                            print(f"Page {page_num + 1}: URL - {url}\nString - {url_string}\nBroken!")
                    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                        print(f"Page {page_num + 1}: URL - {url}\nString - {url_string}\nBroken! Error: {e}")

# Close the PDF file
pdf_file.close()
```

Currently, in the following script, I am geeting the following result for string:

```
String - None
```

Also tried all the codes available here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614726/6697295.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614726/6697295). It seems the text must be extracted by getting the text that overlaps the rect of the href

Comment: @Elias Thank you for your response I tried the code available in the link you provided but it is not working. I can only get URLs but I want both URL and text.

Comment: Hi @martin-thoma 

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The process is theoretically simple which ever applications you use, the problem is finding the inter relationships.

[image]

First the contents need decoding to be searchable for the URI data, then that entry needs to back link to the surface locations, in this case 2 words then one, but how do we know it is that location? The URI does not say that Page as it's page-less. So we backtrack where first URI `/Annots[46 0 R` is included in this Page `42 0 obj`.

```
46 0 obj
<</A<</S/URI/URI(https://www.abc.com.html#C_Concept.dita_da0d66f6-405e-4db6-8845-1578e253f5bd)>>/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/Rect[132.6 305.141 187.28 314.233]>>
endobj

42 0 obj
<</Contents[43 0 R 44 0 R]/BleedBox[0 0 612 792]/Type/Page/Resources 45 0 R/Parent 7 0 R/CropBox[0 0 612 792]/Annots[46 0 R 47 0 R 48 0 R 49 0 R 50 0 R]/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/TrimBox[0 0 612 792]>>
endobj
```

Likewise that page is listed as second entry of `/Kids[3 0 R 42 0 R` among pages

```
7 0 obj
<</Kids[3 0 R 42 0 R 51 0 R 69 0 R 84 0 R 104 0 R 111 0 R 116 0 R 130 0 R 146 0 R]/Type/Pages/Count 10/Parent 6 0 R>>
endobj
```

So now we know we are looking for those words on page 2 at that location. And to avoid doing the same all over again (as a human intuition) if the next URI is slight lower it must be the lower word Location

Thus:

```
47 0 obj
<</A<</S/URI/URI(https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_da0d66f6-405e-4db6-8845-1578e253f5bd)>>/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/Rect[132.6 293.141 190.85 302.233]>>
endobj
```

should be Enhancements.

So C#, CMD, JS, VBA, Python or PyPDF the loops are just the same as per human.

The greater remaining challenge is, defining a copy and paste function at that location on Page2 and that is where perhaps PyMuPDF may have some better rect handling. However beware, units in Y can there be needing reversal, raising yet another challenge.

As an example here is that area as defined by a MuTool "Trace" page 2 and we see X=132.6 however if we searched for Y=305.141 we would miss finding Y=307.299. Thus aligning Y is a question of setting a known tolerance/range. For example 290 to 310.

```
        <span font="GFEDCB+TimesNewRomanPSMT" wmode="0" bidi="0" trm="10 0 0 10">
            <g unicode="A" glyph="A" x="132.6" y="307.299" adv=".72216799"/>
            <g unicode="S" glyph="S" x="139.82" y="307.299" adv=".55615237"/>
            <g unicode="E" glyph="E" x="145.38" y="307.299" adv=".61083987"/>
            <g unicode="L" glyph="L" x="153.98" y="307.299" adv=".61083987"/>
            <g unicode="o" glyph="o" x="160.09" y="307.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="a" glyph="a" x="165.09" y="307.299" adv=".44384767"/>
            <g unicode="d" glyph="d" x="169.53" y="307.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="i" glyph="i" x="174.53" y="307.299" adv=".27783204"/>
            <g unicode="n" glyph="n" x="177.31" y="307.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="g" glyph="g" x="182.31" y="307.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="E" glyph="E" x="132.6" y="295.299" adv=".61083987"/>
            <g unicode="n" glyph="n" x="138.71" y="295.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="h" glyph="h" x="143.71" y="295.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="a" glyph="a" x="148.71" y="295.299" adv=".44384767"/>
            <g unicode="n" glyph="n" x="153.15001" y="295.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="c" glyph="c" x="158.15001" y="295.299" adv=".44384767"/>
            <g unicode="e" glyph="e" x="162.59001" y="295.299" adv=".44384767"/>
            <g unicode="m" glyph="m" x="167.03002" y="295.299" adv=".77783206"/>
            <g unicode="e" glyph="e" x="174.81002" y="295.299" adv=".44384767"/>
            <g unicode="n" glyph="n" x="179.25002" y="295.299" adv=".5"/>
            <g unicode="t" glyph="t" x="184.25002" y="295.299" adv=".27783204"/>
            <g unicode="s" glyph="s" x="187.03002" y="295.299" adv=".38916017"/>
        </span>
```

So we could use a command line to read and display those values. This is not the easiest, it just shows it's possible. However there are simpler ways you can program using Python libraries direct.

[image]

### And thus we come to the simplest answer

of all which is to search a HTML reproduction of the page(s) and tidy up that result by splitting off the unwanted head and tail then replace the `&#160;` with space characters.

[image]

```
\poppler\bin>pdftohtml -noframes -hidden abc.pdf 1>nul 2>nul

\poppler\bin>type abc.html |find /i "https:"|more
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_da0d66f6-405e-4db6-8845-1578e253f5bd">ASE&#160;Loading</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_da0d66f6-405e-4db6-8845-1578e253f5bd">Enhancements</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_ff4df4be-c3c5-494c-9d84-3d5ed1409863">PROD&#160;2134&#160;L-Fan</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_ff4df4be-c3c5-494c-9d84-3d5ed1409863">and&#160;C+L-Fan</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_ff4df4be-c3c5-494c-9d84-3d5ed1409863">Support.</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#omnidirectional--support1">LAT&#160;Based</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#omnidirectional--support1">Omnidirectional</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#omnidirectional--support1">Add/Drop&#160;Topology&#160;</a>omnidirectional&#160;add/drop&#160;can&#160;be&#160;implemented&#160;on&#160;a&#160;node&#160;to&#160;provide&#160;redundancy&#160;or<br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html">SNMP&#160;MIB&#160;support&#160;</a>The&#160;standard&#160;optical&#160;Simple&#160;Network&#160;Management&#160;Protocol&#160;(SNMP)&#160;Management<br/><a href="https://www.abc.html">is&#160;enabled&#160;in&#160;PROD</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html">2134</a><br/>
PROD&#160;2134&#160;platform.&#160;Also,&#160;from&#160;R7.9.1&#160;Release&#160;onwards&#160;specific&#160;support&#160;is&#160;enabled<br/>for&#160;the&#160;OTS&#160;SNMP&#160;MIB.&#160;See&#160;<a href="https://cfnng.abc.com/mibs">C&#160;SNMP&#160;MIBs&#160;</a>for&#160;details.<br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html">APC&#160;enhancements</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html">Fan&#160;Failure</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html">Reco&#160;(BFR)</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#c-ILT-l">PRODK-ILT-L&#160;Line&#160;</a>The&#160;new&#160;PRODK-ILT-L&#160;line&#160;card&#160;for&#160;the&#160;PROD&#160;2134&#160;optical&#160;line&#160;system&#160;amplifies<br/><a href="https://www.abc.html#c-ILT-l">Card</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#c-LAT-l">PRODK-LAT-L&#160;Line&#160;</a>The&#160;new&#160;PRODK-LAT-L&#160;line&#160;card&#160;for&#160;the&#160;PROD&#160;2134&#160;optical&#160;line&#160;system&#160;performs&#160;the<br/><a href="https://www.abc.html#c-LAT-l">Card</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_782e3652-dcc9-49f9-8181-9f2f30a46ae4">Port&#160;Status&#160;for</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_782e3652-dcc9-49f9-8181-9f2f30a46ae4">Breakout&#160;Modules</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_dce6c2f9-fc32-43e0-aec5-abc2d4426347">Port&#160;Status&#160;for</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_dce6c2f9-fc32-43e0-aec5-abc2d4426347">Mux/Demux&#160;Patch</a><br/>
<a href="https://www.abc.html#C_Concept.dita_dce6c2f9-fc32-43e0-aec5-abc2d4426347">Panel</a><br/>
-- More  --
```